# Nested iterable mapping / filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I would like to map and filter the elements of nested iterables in Python matching specific conditions, something like:

```
items = [func(item) if map_condition(item) else item for item in items if filter_condition(item)]
```

but generalized to nested iterables, so that e.g. an input like:

```
items = [[1, 2], [[3, 4, 4.0, 5], 5], 6.0, 'ciao', 7, 8, {1, 2, 3}]
```

applying a function `nested_map_filter(items, func, map_condition, filter_condition)` like these:

```
new_items = nested_filter_map(items, str, lambda x: isinstance(x, int), lambda x: not isinstance(x, str))
new_items = nested_filter_map(items, str, None, None)
new_items = nested_filter_map(items, str, None, lambda x: not isinstance(x, float))
new_items = nested_filter_map(items, str, lambda x: isinstance(x, int), None)
new_items = nested_filter_map(items, str, lambda x: isinstance(x, int), lambda x: not isinstance(x, float))
```

would result, respectively, in:

```
# [['1', '2'], [['3', '4', 4.0, '5'], '5'], 6.0, '7', '8', {'2', '1', '3'}]
# [['1', '2'], [['3', '4', '4.0', '5'], '5'], '6.0', 'ciao', '7', '8', {'2', '1', '3'}]
# [['1', '2'], [['3', '4', '5'], '5'], 'ciao', '7', '8', {'2', '1', '3'}]
# [['1', '2'], [['3', '4', 4.0, '5'], '5'], 6.0, 'ciao', '7', '8', {'2', '1', '3'}]
# [['1', '2'], [['3', '4', '5'], '5'], 'ciao', '7', '8', {'2', '1', '3'}]
```

Is there a standard construct or something in the standard library to do this?

**EDIT**: I have improved the terminology so that `map` / `filter` match the meaning of the built-ins and added more test-cases.

---

## EDIT

I have written something like this, which does the job.

(**EDIT 2**) My questions are more: am I reinventing the wheel? Is it possible / convenient to write this as a generator?

```
def deep_filter_map(
        items,
        func=None,
        map_condition=None,
        filter_condition=None,
        avoid=(str, bytes),
        max_depth=-1):
    if func is None:
        def func(x): return x
    if map_condition is None:
        def map_condition(_): return True
    if filter_condition is None:
        def filter_condition(_): return True
    container = type(items)
    new_items = []
    for item in items:
        try:
            no_expand = avoid and isinstance(item, avoid)
            if no_expand or max_depth == 0 or item == next(iter(item)):
                raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
            if filter_condition(item):
                new_items.append(func(item) if map_condition(item) else item)
        else:
            new_items.append(
                deep_filter_map(
                    item, func, map_condition, filter_condition, avoid, max_depth - 1))
    return container(new_items)
```

Comment: What do you expect when `nested_filters([{1, 2, 3}], lambda : 1, lambda x: isinstance(x, int))`?

Comment: Is `items` always made up of lists, tuples, ints and floats?

Comment: @Farhan.K `items` can contain anything

Comment: @DanielMesejo should be: `[{1}]` obviously, as the container is expected to be preserved

Comment: It's not obvious. For example, how do you expect to handle `str` and `bytes` objects? Those *are* containers too. In any event, no there is not built-in way to do this, but you can write your own pretty easily. And this isn't really a filter.

Comment: So it does not really filter any elements but apply the function only to those with the correct type? In this case, it might be simpler to write a wrapper for the function that only applies it to the given type (or generally, if some condition is met) and otherwise returns the original object.

Comment: @tobias_k I guess this should be called `map`, let me edit this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such function in the standard library, but you could improve the reusability (and maintainability and testability) of your own solution by splitting it up into smaller parts that can then be used independently. First, a wrapper function for conditionally applying some function, and then two functions for applying any function to or conditionally filtering the elements of nested iterables.

```
def cond_apply(cond, func):
    return lambda x: func(x) if cond(x) else x

def deep_map(func, lst, types=(list, tuple, set)):
    if isinstance(lst, types):
        return type(lst)(deep_map(func, x) for x in lst)
    else:
        return func(lst)

def deep_filter(cond, lst, types=(list, tuple, set)):
    if isinstance(lst, types):
        return type(lst)(deep_filter(cond, x) for x in lst if isinstance(x, types) or cond(x))
    else:
        return lst

items = [[1, 2], [[3, 4, 4.0, 5], 5], 6.0, 'ciao', 7, 8, {1, 2, 3}]
print(deep_map(cond_apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), str),
               deep_filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str), items)))
# [['1', '2'], [['3', '4', 4.0, '5'], '5'], 6.0, '7', '8', {'1', '3', '2'}]
```

This way, the function can be used individually, and you could also e.g. invert the `map` and `filter` steps. Of course, you could still wrap those three function into another single function providing all the parameters for easier usage.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I can imagine that having separate functions may make sense. However, performance wise, if both are required, my solution seems to be significantly more efficient.